# Issues proxying request with HAproxy

Tags: devops, load-balancing, haproxy

We're trying to set up HAproxy enterprise for reverse proxying requests to our internal microservices. The configuration we have created accepts all traffic on port 80 and has multiple backends to proxy requests to. But the requests are not getting proxied all the time in a stable manner. We have around 10 URLs and everytime we restart the hapee service some of the URLs stop working.

```
frontend example.com
    bind *:80
    mode http
    acl ACL_abc hdr(host) -i abc.example.com
    acl ACL_url1 hdr(host) -i abc.example.com && path /url1
    acl ACL_def hdr(host) -i def.example.com
    acl ACL_pqr hdr(host) -i pqr.example.com
    use backend abc if ACL_abc
    use backend url1 if ACL_url1
    use backend def if ACL_def
    use backend pqr if ACL_pqr

backend abc
    http-request set-header Host abc.internal.com
    server server1 abc.internal.com

backend url1
    http-request set-header Host url1.internal.com
    server server1 url1.internal.com

backend def
    http-request set-header Host def.internal.com
    server server1 def.internal.com

backend pqr
    http-request set-header Host pqr.internal.com
    server server1 pqr.internal.com
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot or sample input-output of one successful and one failed.. and then add logs of haproxy.

Comment: One of the HAProxy Enterprise Feature ( https://www.haproxy.com/products/haproxy-enterprise/ )  is **Expert Support 24x7x365**. I strongly recommend to open a request to the excellent HAProxy Team.

Comment: @RajaRavindra On success it displays the correct page and UI. But on failure, it shows "503 - No servers available"

Comment: @lakshaygaur This means that frontend application is down. Are you sure your frontend is live? Try telnet maybe